# printing one element if every element in the array are equal while printing the largest if all elements aren't equal

Tags: java, if-statement, arraylist

I wrote a code to output the largest value of a sequence if numbers given by the user. If the user only inputs equal values the same output will be repeated the number of inputs given by the user.

The problem here is that even though I wrote an if condition to avoid the repetition of the same output but it doesn't work. I would really appreciate the help.

Problem:

```
int y = 0;
        for(int i : a){
            int v = 0;
            if(i == a.get(0)){
                y = y + 1;
            }
            for(int o : a){
                if(i >= o){
                    v = v + 1;
                }
            }
            if(y == a.size()){
                System.out.println("Largest_num = "+a.get(0));
            }
            else if((v == a.size())&&(y != a.size())){
                System.out.println("Largest_num = "+i);
            }
```

Whole code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
class Noice{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner obj = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println();
        ArrayList<Integer>a = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        System.out.print("Enter length: ");
        int d = obj.nextInt();
        System.out.println();
        for(int i = 0; i < d; i++){
            int c = i + 1;
            System.out.print("Num"+c+" = ");
            int b = obj.nextInt();
            a.add(b);
        }
        int y = 0;
        for(int i : a){
            int v = 0;
            if(i == a.get(0)){
                y = y + 1;
            }
            for(int o : a){
                if(i >= o){
                    v = v + 1;
                }
            }
            if(y == a.size()){
                System.out.println("Largest_num = "+a.get(0));
            }
            else if((v == a.size())&&(y != a.size())){
                System.out.println("Largest_num = "+i);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm having trouble understanding what each of your variables are doing, it's good practice to use variable names that explain it's purpose.

From what I *am* able to tell, `y` is keeping track of how many of the values are equal to the first value in the array. Your first if condition then checks to see if the number of identical values (`y`) is the same as the size of the array. If that is the case, then you shouldn't need an `else if`, and just an `else` should suffice, if I am understanding the problem correctly.

I'm also struggling to understand what the loop `for(int o : a)` and variable `v` are doing. Again, it's hard to follow given that your variable names don't depict their functionality, but it seems like you can scrap that nested loop and just keep track of a running maximum variable. Before `for(int i : a)`, you can add something like `int max = a.get(0);`. Then, within your `for` loop, if you come across a number bigger than `max`, you update `max` with that value. Doing it this way, though, wouldn't require any conditions at all, and you can just output `max` at the end of the program.